# Selenium Chrome Screenshot - html2canvas

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html2canvas

I was using html2canvas.js library for taking full page screen shot along with selenium.

```
public class ChromeCanvasCapture {

    private static final String APP_URL = "http://www.flipkart.com";

    public static String getFileContent(String filePath)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        String fileContent = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        return fileContent;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver webDriver = null;

        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "D:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            webDriver.get(APP_URL);
            webDriver.manage().window().maximize();

            if (webDriver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
                // scroll to the bottom of the page
                ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver)                        .executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
                // //scroll to the top of the page
                ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver)
                    .executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,0)");
            }

            String jsFile = getFileContent("html2canvas.js");
            jsFile = jsFile
                + " var webDriverCallback = arguments[arguments.length - 1]; html2canvas(document.body, {onrendered: function(canvas) {var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');; webDriverCallback(img); }";
            System.out.println(jsFile);
            webDriver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (webDriver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
                JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
                Object result = executor.executeAsyncScript(jsFile);
                String imageString = String.valueOf(result);
                byte[] imageData = Base64.decodeBase64(imageString);
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    "C:\\Captures\\canvas_captured.png");
                outputStream.write(imageData);
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // webDriver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I have kept html2canvas.js file in class path of my java project. The java script code I am using to get screenshot is:

```
var webDriverCallback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];

html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');;
        webDriverCallback(img);
    }
});
```

I am able to capture the full page screen shot for the flipkart page but with out any images in it.

I am not able to use TakeScreenshot utility from chrome because it doesn't allow to take full page screen shot with chrome browser.

[image: Screenshot using canvas2html.js]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this following.
But you have to handle some wait till all the images are loaded.
It has the option to skip the repetitive elements, as the flipkart's header search banner is the repetitive one, I'm passing that as a element to hide.

```
    driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'fk-ui-ccarousel-supercontainer requirecss-HPS')]")));

    WebElement header = driver.findElement(By.id("fk-header"));
    //As header is repeating we are giving it as repetitive element so that it will remove it while taking screenshot
    Files.copy(Utils.makeFullScreenshot(driver, header), new File("D:\\fsile.png"));
```

**Utils.Java**
It is a modification of GalenFramework's [FullPageScreenShot](https://github.com/galenframework/galen/blob/galen-1.6.4/src/main/java/net/mindengine/galen/utils/GalenUtils.java)

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Utils {

private static final String JS_RETRIEVE_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO = "var pr = window.devicePixelRatio; if (pr != undefined && pr != null)return pr; else return 1.0;";

private static void hideScroll(WebDriver driver) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';");
}

private static void showScroll(WebDriver driver) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'visible';");
}

private static void showHideElements(WebDriver driver, Boolean hide, WebElement... skipElements) {
    String display;
    if (hide) {
        display = "none";
    } else {
        display = "block";
    }
    if (skipElements != null) {
        for (WebElement skipElement : skipElements) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = '" + display + "';", skipElement);
        }
    }
}

private static byte[] getScreenShot(WebDriver driver) {
    return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
}

//The code that does the job
public static File makeFullScreenshot(WebDriver driver, WebElement... skipElements) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //Scroll to bottom to make sure all elements loaded correctly
    // scrollVerticallyTo(driver, (int) longScrollHeight);

    // scroll up first to start taking screenshots
    scrollVerticallyTo(driver, 0);
    hideScroll(driver);
    //No need to hide elements for first attempt
    byte[] bytes = getScreenShot(driver);

    showHideElements(driver, true, skipElements);
    long longScrollHeight = (Long) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return Math.max("
            + "document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,"
            + "document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,"
            + "document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight);"
    );

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    int capturedWidth = image.getWidth();
    int capturedHeight = image.getHeight();

    Double devicePixelRatio = ((Number) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(JS_RETRIEVE_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO)).doubleValue();

    int scrollHeight = (int) longScrollHeight;

    File file = File.createTempFile("screenshot", ".png");

    int adaptedCapturedHeight = (int) (((double) capturedHeight) / devicePixelRatio);

    BufferedImage resultingImage;

    if (Math.abs(adaptedCapturedHeight - scrollHeight) > 40) {
        int scrollOffset = adaptedCapturedHeight;

        int times = scrollHeight / adaptedCapturedHeight;
        int leftover = scrollHeight % adaptedCapturedHeight;

        final BufferedImage tiledImage = new BufferedImage(capturedWidth, (int) (((double) scrollHeight) * devicePixelRatio), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2dTile = tiledImage.createGraphics();
        g2dTile.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        int scroll = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < times - 1; i++) {
            scroll += scrollOffset;
            scrollVerticallyTo(driver, scroll);
            BufferedImage nextImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(getScreenShot(driver)));
            g2dTile.drawImage(nextImage, 0, (i + 1) * capturedHeight, null);
        }
        if (leftover > 0) {
            scroll += scrollOffset;
            scrollVerticallyTo(driver, scroll);
            BufferedImage nextImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(getScreenShot(driver)));
            BufferedImage lastPart = nextImage.getSubimage(0, nextImage.getHeight() - (int) (((double) leftover) * devicePixelRatio), nextImage.getWidth(), leftover);
            g2dTile.drawImage(lastPart, 0, times * capturedHeight, null);
        }

        scrollVerticallyTo(driver, 0);

        resultingImage = tiledImage;
    } else {
        resultingImage = image;
    }
    showScroll(driver);
    showHideElements(driver, false, skipElements);
    ImageIO.write(resultingImage, "png", file);
    return file;
}

private static void scrollVerticallyTo(WebDriver driver, int scroll) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, " + scroll + ");");
    try {
        waitUntilItIsScrolledToPosition(driver, scroll);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       // LOG.trace("Interrupt error during scrolling occurred.", e);
    }
}

private static void waitUntilItIsScrolledToPosition(WebDriver driver, int scrollPosition) throws InterruptedException {
    int hardTime = 0;//SCREENSHOT_FULLPAGE_SCROLLWAIT
    if (hardTime > 0) {
        Thread.sleep(hardTime);
    }
    int time = 250;//SCREENSHOT_FULLPAGE_SCROLLTIMEOUT
    boolean isScrolledToPosition = false;
    while (time >= 0 && !isScrolledToPosition) {
        Thread.sleep(50);
        time -= 50;
        isScrolledToPosition = Math.abs(obtainVerticalScrollPosition(driver) - scrollPosition) < 3;
    }
}

private static int obtainVerticalScrollPosition(WebDriver driver) {
    Long scrollLong = (Long) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;");
    return scrollLong.intValue();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**html2canvas** script works by traversing through the DOM of the page It gathers information of all the elements there, which it then uses to build a representation of the page which means it actually does not take a screenshot of the page but builds a representation from reading the DOM ie)whole image is created on the clients browser so it does not circumvent any browser content policy restrictions either

Under the same origin policy, a web browser permits scripts contained in a web page to access data from another web page, provided only if both web pages have the same origin. so all the images that the script uses need to reside under the same origin for it to be able to read them.But in your case the images are loaded in flipkart.com from different domain http://img5a.flixcart.com(You can verify this from src attribute of the images in flipkart)

The other option you have is to use a proxy but currently there is no html2canvas [proxy](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/wiki/Proxies) for java.If it is your absolute necessity you can build one.

Other solution if you're interested

**pseudocode**

```
document.documentElement.scrollHeight //gives total page height

document.documentElement.clientHeight //gives current screen height

//You can write ur logic ex : if scroll height is greater than client height scroll
if(document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight)
//take screenshot and then scroll(Do this till the end of the page)
}
```

In the end join all screenshots to a single image file

Hope this helps you...Kindly get back if you have any queries

Comment: I tried the solution you have suggested. But it failes in case of flipkart. As the header is static, it appears on all the screen shots.

Comment: @PriyankThakkar Yes this is one of the disadvantage of this approach...you have to remove the main menu manually using javascript after first scroll document.getElementById("fk-header").remove();